# this.slides.length() Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

`console.log(this.slides.length());` prints `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.`
On `setTimeout` of 100, this prints.

Is there any method to identify a child component is fully loaded from the parent component?

```html
<ion-content padding class="ttct-app-content">
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-compose',
  templateUrl: 'compose.html',
})
export class Compose {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.slides.length()); //Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    //works
    /*
    setTimeout(()=>{    
      console.log(this.slides.length());
    },100); 
    */

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried other hooks?

Comment: @BogdanC:  yes I tried all the hooks in this article
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#!#spy

Comment: Is this a bug in ionic-2 ?

Comment: Please add the ionic version you are using so that I could test it.

Comment: @BogdanC : "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",

Comment: I'm using the latest version, and I get the same problem. I noticed that all methods are available, but exclusively length() returns an error. setTimeout does not work at all cases

Comment: @MELWINVINCENT For my problem, I decided to use ionViewDidLoad and a setInterval loop checking for this.slides._slides to be ready. Once it's ready, I clear the interval and use the method. I know it's not the best solution but it's been working for me.

Comment: @LucasMedina definitely is not the best approach. This should be fixed by Ionic team

Comment: @DanielRodriguez I definitely agree. Since I don't really understand the architecture behind how Ionic works, and I was pretty fresh to Angular 4, I couldn't come up with any other solution for my previous case :( I hope they can fix it, or at the very least, write a documentation for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (you don't need to import anything else):

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log(this.slides.length());
}
```

Tried also with a slider loaded using a ngFor and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing that console log in a:

```
ionViewDidLoad() { 

}
```

Rather then ngAfterViewInit().

Answer (score 0):

How about raising an event from child's onInit and watching it in parent?
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is happening because the `<ion-slide></ion-slide>` children are not initialized on the page hooks. That's why when you put `setTimeout()` works, because until then they get initialized and added to the `<ion-slides>` parent.
After the hooks they are there, you can check with a button click to read the `length()` property.
You can find a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38846793).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create this method to access to lenght

```
 get slides_length() {
    if (this.slides && this.slides._slides) {
        return this.slides._slides.length;
    }

    return 0;
}
```