# Angular - Access list of child components on page load

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchildren

I am using Angular 10 for a side-project of mine. I have a page that, on page load, retrieves a list of entries (in this case specifically `spells`) from the server and renders 1 child-component (`<app-spell>` component) per entry on that page. The user can (this is optional) specify a url parameter called `name` and if he does and there is an entry for which it is true `spell.name === name` then I want to scroll to the component of that entry.

I am stuck trying to get the point where I have access to a list of these children. Ì was planning on using `ViewChildren` to get the list of child-components. However, there don't appear to be any proper lifecycle hooks where it has accurate values. Further, even when trying to use document.querySelector (I know ahead of time that I will have a component with id "Arawns-Changing-Scales") I appear to be unable to get my required HTML Elements:

1. `ngAfterContentInit` : You can't access `ViewChildren` in general in this hook. `document.querySelector`-calls return null.
2. `ngAfterViewInit`:  The entries haven't been fetched at that point and neither have the child-components been initialized. Thus `ViewChildren` returns an empty `QueryList`. document.querySelector` returns null
3. `ngOnInit`: The child-components haven't been initialized. Thus `ViewChildren` returns an empty `QueryList`.  `document.querySelector` returns null

And after that I'm out of appropriate seeming lifecycle hooks. I've tried what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763248/angular-2-life-cycle-hook-after-all-children-are-initialized) and put my attempt to access my `ViewChildren` into a setTimeout callback, this just returned the same as not using a timeout at all. Other questions I found were using clicks or other user-triggered events to fire a scroll, which is not the case for me.

Where can I get some kind of HTMLElements/Components during the loading of the page ?

```
## spells.component.html

        <!-- Spells -->
        <div *ngFor="let spell of spells; let i = index">
            <app-spell
            #spellElements
            [id]="spell.name.replaceAll(' ', '-').replace('\'', '')"
            [index] = "i"
            [cardData] = "spell"
            *ngIf="hasSelectedClasses(spell)"
            ></app-spell>
        </div>
```

```
## spells.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spells',
  templateUrl: './spells.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spells.component.scss']
})
export class SpellsComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  panelIsOpenArray: boolean[];
  spells: SpellObject[];

  @ViewChildren("spellElements") spellElements: QueryList<any>;

  constructor(
    private spellService: SpellService,
    public routingService: RoutingService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spellService.list().pipe(first()).subscribe(
      (spells: SpellObject[]) => {
        this.spells = spells;
        this.panelIsOpenArray = [];
        for (let spell of spells){
          this.panelIsOpenArray.push(true);
        };

        console.log("After init");
        this.scrollToSpellInUrl();
      },
      error => this.routingService.routeToErrorPage(error)
    );
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void{
    setTimeout(_=> {
      console.log("After view init in timeout");
      this.scrollToSpellInUrl()
    });

    console.log("After view init normal")
    this.scrollToSpellInUrl();
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void{
    console.log("After content init");
    this.scrollToSpellInUrl();
  }

  scrollToSpellInUrl(){
    console.log(this.spellElements);
    console.log(document.getElementById("Arawns-Changing-Scales");
    console.log(document.querySelector("#Arawns-Changing-Scales"));
    return;
  }

  hasSelectedClasses(spell: SpellObject): boolean{
    //For all intents and purposes, based on some other data and this
    //data this function returns sometimes true sometimes false, more 
    //is not relevant for this question.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ViewChildren](https://v10.angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) annotation to watch for SpellComponents. The annotation exposes a [QueryList](https://v10.angular.io/api/core/QueryList) which is first populated inside the ngAfterViewInit hook. In your case, your are fetching the spells in an asynchronous way and you are not able to get them in time for the ngAfterViewInit hook. However Querylist has a `changes` property which is an Observable that will emit any time a SpellComponent is added, removed or moved from the template.

```
  @ViewChildren(SpellComponent)
  public spellsComponents: QueryList<SpellComponent>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.spellsComponents.changes.subscribe(queryList => {});
  }
```

On each emit, we can search in the queryList parameter. But before Here is my SpellComponent:

```
export class SpellComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

We will use the name Input to identify our spell components. I inject [ElementRef](https://v10.angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) as it will able us to use the [element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

```
this.spellsComponents.changes.subscribe(queryList => {
  const target = queryList.find(cmp => cmp.name === "foo");
  target.element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
});
```

Done. Here is a live demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmjzwj-jffmyr?file=app.module.ts.

Comment: To the point, solved the problem immediately, concise and clear in the reasoning and on top of that a stackblitz. If there is a perfect SO answer, this comes close it. Thank you very much!